# BadZipFile: File is not a zip file in .xslx converter into CSV

Tags: python

I'm running a code to convert several .xlsv files to CSV.

I ran the code for a small sample of 9 files and it worked.

But when I run the code for a larger sample I get the following error:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

print("ok")
```

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Sandy Gomes\Desktop\4") #Change directory to folder1
filenames = glob.glob("*.xlsx") #List of filenames

print(filenames)
```

```
path = (r"C:\Users\Sandy Gomes\Desktop\4")

files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\Sandy Gomes\Desktop\4\*.xlsx")

for f in files:
    out = f.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_excel(f) 
    df.to_csv(out)
```

[image]

Comment: So did you independently verify that the particular .xlsx file, which is generating the error, is valid? Also, there are many results if you search for this particular error in regards to `pandas` and reading `xlsx` files. In order for us to not waste our time providing you with answers that you've already tried, please share here what you have tried and researched so far. If you haven't tried or researched anything, then please do that before posting here.

Comment: Seems like one of your file is corrupted or protected. You can easily catch the bad file by [handling exceptions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exception-handling/) in your code.